# Working of betatron

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-induction

Can anyone please explain me the working principle of betatron and is it better than cyclotron or not in terms of accelerating particles at greater speed and energy consumption by the instrument used to accelerate

Comment: Better at what? As to how it works, Wikipedia has articles on both - start there. But, mainly this sounds like you want us to do your homework for you...

Comment: Actually it is not at all my homework as it is not in our syllabus

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question

Comment: 'Homework' in the context of this SE (see Meta) consists of pretty much anything you just dump on us expecting an answer. You seem to not have done any research yourself. Go read the Wikipedia articles - those answer at least some of your question.

Comment: I have read the wiki articles and a book called resnick halliday but could not understood the working principle

Comment: Dont take it wrong way but I did not dumped the question on you it is not compulsory for anyone to do it, it was my doubt so I asked it

Comment: So what do you understand about the working principle of the betatron? Start there.

Comment: It accelerates electrons by making them to go in a circular path in which the field is perpendicular to plane which is the reason for its centripetal acceleration (my understanding was limited to this)

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_en-GBGB786GB786&ei=nh9SW-PlAtS0gQaDi6vICw&q=difference+between+betatron+and+cyclotron&oq=difference+between+betatron+and+cyclotron&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i8i30k1.16051.24858.0.25491.23.23.0.0.0.0.133.2271.16j7.23.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.5.448...0i8i7i30k1j0i7i30k1.0.g3JARmWRTxk

Answer (score 1):

well, I can try but in absence of diagrams, get details in the references-

The Betatron [developed by D.W. Kerst] is a circular induction accelerator used for electron acceleration.

> The word betatron derives from the fact that electrons are often called beta – particles at least in radioactivity.

**The arrangement-**

A **toroidal** shaped vacuum chamber **encircles the core** of a large magnet.

The magnetic field is produced by pulsed coils;

the magnetic flux inside the radius of the vacuum chamber changes with time.

Increasing flux generates an azimuthal electric field **which accelerates** electrons in the chamber.

> In the absence of an air gap, there is little magnetic flux outside the core.
>
> An air gap is included to divert some of the magnetic flux into the vacuum chamber.
>
> By the proper choice of gap width, the vertical magnetic field can be adjusted to confine electrons to a circular orbit in the vacuum chamber.

In summary, the simple betatron has **the following elements:**

1. A pulsed magnet circuit to accelerate electrons by inductive fields.
2. An air gap to force magnetic field into the beam transport region; electrons follow circular orbits in the bending field.

   3.Over most of the acceleration cycle, electrons travel near the velocity of light.

   During the acceleration cycle, the electrons make revolutions and travel through cavities.

The stable orbit for the electrons satisfies

> theta(0) =  2.pi. r(0)^2.H(0)

where
theta (0) is the flux within the area enclosed by the electron orbit,

r(0) is  the radius of the electron orbit, and

H(0) is  the magnetic field at  the orbit

> In other words, the magnetic field at the orbit must be half the average magnetic field over its circular cross section:

**The limitation-**

> The maximum energy that a betatron can impart is limited by the strength of the magnetic field due to the saturation of iron and by practical size of the magnet core. The next generation of accelerators, the synchrotron , overcame these limitations.
>
> References-1. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betatron
>               2. physics.tutorcircle.com/modern-physics/betatron.html
>               3. web.mit.edu/course/22/22.09/ClassHandouts/Charged..